# How to track symbol created during code loading in Ruby in a thread safe manner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I'd like to track symbol created during code loading in Ruby. I was planning to monkey patch Kernel#require and diff Symbol.all_symbols after and before calling to the built-in #require:

In `loaded.rb`

```
def create_symbols
  s1 = :static_literal
  s2 = :"symbol with interpolation #{s1}"
  s3 = "dynamic symbol".to_sym
end
```

In main.rb

```
$new = []
def patch
  Kernel.module_eval do
    alias_method :org_require, :require
    define_method :require do |path|
    before = Symbol.all_symbols
    r = org_require path
    $new << Symbol.all_symbols - before
    r
  end
end

patch
# #require can be called in other threads as well, e.g. in a Rails app. This is just an example
require "./loaded.rb"
```

$new will only include :static_literal, which is what I need. But the problem is that the patch isn't threadsafe:

```
before = Symbol.all_symbols
# calling create_symbols() in between will alter all_symbols and leads to s2 and s3 added  to all_symbols which I don't want to track
r = org_require path
$new << Symbol.all_symbols - before
```

Is there a thread safe way to achieve it?

Comment: Since you are just using the main thread, this doesn't seem to be about thread safety or `multithreading`. It's more about symbols created by the parser vs. those created by the interpreter (i.e. at runtime).

Comment: Sorry, it was just a sample snippet, but the require can happen in any thread. Think about in a Rails app

Comment: What do you mean track? And why do you believe "`$new` will only include :static_literal"? Just running your code as is proves `$new #=> [[:create_symbols, :s1, :static_literal, :s3]]` [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/FarawayIntrepidWorkplace#loaded.rb)